# ClassCastException while loading XMI resource from EMF model

Tags: load, persist, emf, xmi

I want to load an EMF model resource which was persistend before from an Eclipse Plug-in Environment. I tried as follows.

```
// obtain a new resource set

ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

// get the resource 

resSet.getResource(URI.createURI(location), true);
```

`location` is a path relative to the platform, e.g. platform:/resource/Project/default.mymodel

When I try to get the resource using `URI.createURI(...)` I get a `ClassCastException`: "MymodelFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$Factory".

I cannot explain this. Can somebody please help me?

I already tried `URI.createFileURI(location)`. This results in an `IllegalArgumentException`: "invalid relative pathName".

Regards

The stack trace looks as follows.
java.lang.ClassCastException: de.uka.ipd.sdq.pcm.usagemodel.impl.UsagemodelFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$Factory
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.convert(ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$2.delegatedGetFactory(ResourceSetImpl.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.getFactory(ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.getFactory(ResourceFactoryRegistryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.createResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandCreateResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:400)

Comment: But is your code now not under Eclipse but running stand-alone?

Comment: The code is still running in an Eclipse environment. It is the same Eclipse environment in which the model was persisted.

Comment: Could you please post a bit of the stack trace?

Comment: I added parts of the stack trace to the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supposed to be necessary, because the plug-in environment does it for you, but try to register the resource factory:

```
resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(fileExtension, new ModelResourceFactoryImpl());
```

where `fileExtension` is the file extension of the resource to be loaded and the `ModelResourceFactoryImpl` should be a generated class extending `ResourceFactoryImpl`.

However, after removing the following code, the model can be loaded.

```
// Register the XMI resource factory for my extension
Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
Map<String, Object> m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
m.put("myextension", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
```

It seems this was not the proper registration.

Comment: After I removed the registration of the XMI resource factory for my extension, it works.
Thank a lot!

Comment: Did you remove the registration or did you add it? o_O

Comment: I removed the follow.

// Register the XMI resource factory for my extension

    Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
    Map<String, Object> m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
    m.put("myextension", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

Comment: There should be an error there then. You may want to edit my answer to include that information and mark it as accepted so others can benefit from it. Or you can answer your own question!